# Boolean formula vs boolean function.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Is there a technical difference between boolean formulas and boolean functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Boolean *formula* is a concrete string of symbols. A Boolean *function* of $n$ inputs is an assignment of output truth values to each possible choice of $n$ input truth values.

For example, "$p\lor q$" and "$q\lor (p\land\neg q) $" are two different formulas. They happen to describe the same Boolean *function* of two variables.

Comment: You're too fast.

Comment: @dfeuer: Sorry?

Comment: Just don't do it again :-P.

Comment: Also formula is part of language's syntax while Boolean function is part of interpretation (semantics).